# Placing clusters on the same rank in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I would like these two nodes to appear on the same level:

[image]

```
digraph G {
    subgraph cluster1 {
        label="Local Datacenter";
        router1;
        host1;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
        label="Remote Datacenter";
        router2;
        host2;
    }
    router1 -> router2;
    router2 -> host2;
    router1 -> host1;
}
```

I have tried using `rank=same` and `rank=min`, but they aren't giving me what I need.

Interestingly, if I set `rankdir=LR` and comment out the two router-to-host edges, it gives me exactly the look I want - but I would like to leave the edges intact.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may simply modify the edge between the routers:

```
router1 -> router2[constraint=false];
```

[`constraint`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint) indicates whether the edge should be used in the ranking of the nodes.

Answer (score 105):

You may use the [`newrank`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:newrank) graph attribute (added in GraphViz 2.30) to activate the new ranking algorithm which allows defining `rank=same` for nodes which belong to clusters.

Add the following line at the top:

```
newrank=true;
```

Add the following line *after* the cluster definitions:

```
{ rank=same; router1; router2; }
```

Here's the resulting graph:

[image: routers with same rank]

Comment: This undocumented `newrank` thing also solved my (related but different) problem -- trying to get dot to put clusters on different rows, by putting an invisible edge between nodes in the clusters.  Without `newrank`, this works as expected... *provided* you define "ordinary" subgraphs (whose names don't begin with "cluster").  If you make them clusters, suddenly dot doesn't mind having edges between nodes on the same rank!  Ugh.

Comment: This is much more intuitive, and with predictable results than the `constraint=false` method. Thanks for this.

Comment: `constraint = false` doesn't work for big graphs. It puts it somewhere in siberia and not right next to it.

Comment: The really very sparse explanation in the official [`rank`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/rank/) documentation refers for the details to the answer to the SO question [*Rank attribute is confusing to me*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149834/rank-attribute-is-confusing-to-me).