# top-down subgraphs, left-right inside subgraphs

Tags: graphviz, subgraph

I'd like to have my graph looks like this:

[image]

But I can only get this:

[image]

The problem is, `rankdir` [does not work](http://www.graphviz.org/bugs/b1279.html) in `subgraph`. 
So, how to emulate it?

The code:

```
digraph G {
    node [shape = circle]
    0 [style = invis]

    0 -> "0A"

    subgraph clusterA {
        label=A
        "0A"
        "1A"
        "2A" -> "0A" [label=•]
    }

    subgraph clusterB {
        label=B
        "0B"
        "1B"
        "2B" -> "0B" [label=•]
    }

        subgraph clusterC {
        label=C
        "0C"
        "1C"
        "2C" -> "0C" [label=•]
    }

    subgraph clusterD {
        label=D
        "0D"
        "1D"
        "2D" -> "0D" [label=•]
    }

    subgraph clusterE {
        label=E
        "0E"
        "1E"
        "2E" -> "0E" [label=•]
    }

    subgraph clusterF {
        label=F
            {node [shape = doublecircle] "0F" "1F"}
        "2F" -> "0F" [label=•]
    }

    "0A" -> "1B" [label=a]
    "1A" -> "2B" [label=a]
    "0B" -> "1C" [label=b]
    "1B" -> "2C" [label=b]
    "0C" -> "1D" [label=c]
    "1C" -> "2D" [label=c]
    "0D" -> "1E" [label=d]
    "1D" -> "2E" [label=d]
    "0E" -> "1F" [label=e]
    "1E" -> "2F" [label=e]
}
```

Comment: https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/887

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Reproducing particular graph layouts usually can be achieved with:

- Invisible nodes and edges
- rank constraints

Here's how I reproduced your graph - or at least a part of it:

```
digraph g {
    rankdir="LR";
    node[shape = circle, fontsize=14];
    fontsize=18;
    labeljust="l";

    edge[style=invis, fontsize=12];

    { rank=same;
        0 [style = invis];
        01 [style = invis];
        02 [style=invis];
        0 -> 01 -> 02;
    }

    subgraph clusterA {
        "0A" -> "1A" -> "2A";
        "2A" -> "0A" [label=".", constraint=false, style=solid];
        label="A";
    }

    subgraph clusterB {
        "0B" -> "1B" -> "2B";
        "2B" -> "0B" [label=".", constraint=false, style=solid];
        label="B";
    }

    subgraph clusterC {
        "0C" -> "1C" -> "2C";
        "2C" -> "0C" [label=".", constraint=false, style=solid];
        label="C";
    }

    0 -> "0A"[style=solid];
    01 -> "0B"[style=invis];
    02 -> "0C"[style=invis];

    // edges between clusters
    edge[constraint=false, style=solid];
    "0A" -> "1B" [label=a]
    "1A" -> "2B" [label=a]
    "0B" -> "1C" [label=b]
    "1B" -> "2C" [label=b]
}
```

This solution is not very intuitive. A couple of points to achieve this:

- I chose `rankdir="LR"` which resulted in nicer edges than `TB`, though it does not really correspond with the direction of the graph
- **Invisible nodes and edges** are use for the top rank nodes (0, 01, 02) in order to have the clusters align left.
- The (invisible) top nodes are forced to the same rank and are linked by invisible edges - this will ensure that the clusters linked to each node appear in the correct order.

The result is:

[image: graphviz output]

Comment: It seems that the algorithm has changed. I get a weird 0C when I paste your solution in viz.js

Comment: I was able to fix it using `group`. See my answer

Answer (score 7):

It looks like rank=same might be a cleaner solution.  Take a look at [Placing clusters on the same rank in Graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824431/placing-clusters-on-the-same-rank-in-graphviz).

You can also use 'constraint=false' and invisible edges to carefully control node rank. This is basically the same answer as the above.

```
digraph G {
    newrank=true; // rank without respect to cluster
    rankdir="LR"; 
    node [shape = circle]
    
    subgraph clusterA {
        a0 -> a1 -> a2 [style = invis] // set node order in cluster
        a2 -> a0 [constraint=false] //don't use this edge for ranking
    }

    subgraph clusterB {
        b0 -> b1 -> b2 [style = invis]
        b2 -> b0  [constraint=false]
    }
    
    a0 -> b1 [constraint=false]
    a1 -> b2 [constraint=false]
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think that would help since the clusters aren't placed on the same rank.

Comment: A very clean answer, also expandable without problems, I tried this up to 5 boxes.

Comment: Works the same without `newrank=true;`.

Answer (score 3):

An update on @marapet's answer using `group`

```
digraph g {
rankdir="LR";
node[shape = circle, fontsize=14];
fontsize=18;
labeljust="l";

edge[style=invis, fontsize=12];

{ rank=same;
    0 [group=a style = invis];
    01 [style = invis];
    02 [group=b style=invis];
    0 -> 01 -> 02;
}

subgraph clusterA {
    "0A" [group=a]
    "0A" -> "1A" -> "2A";
    "2A" -> "0A" [label=".", constraint=false, style=solid];
    label="A";
}

subgraph clusterB {
    "0B" -> "1B" -> "2B";
    "2B" -> "0B" [label=".", constraint=false, style=solid];
    label="B";
}

subgraph clusterC {
    "0C" [group=b]
    "1C" [group=b]
    "0C" -> "1C" -> "2C";
    "2C" -> "0C" [label=".", constraint=false, style=solid];
    label="C";
}

0 -> "0A"[style=solid];
01 -> "0B"[style=invis];
02 -> "0C"[style=invis];

// edges between clusters
edge[constraint=false, style=solid];
"0A" -> "1B" [label=a]
"1A" -> "2B" [label=a]
"0B" -> "1C" [label=b]
"1B" -> "2C" [label=b]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using constraint=false should get the nodes in your subgraphs to turn out the way you want
http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint

```
subgraph clusterB {
    label=B
    "0B"
    "1B"
    "2B" -> "0B" [constraint=false label=•]
}
```

After that you'll find that your subgraphs don't line up with each other the way you want. Something like this could resolve that.

```
"0A" -> "0B" -> "0C" -> "0D" -> "0E" [weight=999 style=invis];
```

Answer (score 0):

rankdir doesn't work directly in the subgraph, but if you add another set of curly braces - whatever that's called - rankdir works.  See below.  Then, obviously you need more tricks to restore the alignment and ordering you're after.

```
digraph G {
    node [shape = circle]
    0 [style = invis]

    0 -> "0A"

    subgraph clusterA {
        label=A
        {
            rank=same
            "0A"
            "1A"
            "2A" -> "0A" [label=•]
        }
    }

    subgraph clusterB {
        label=B
        {
            rank=same
            "0B"
            "1B"
            "2B" -> "0B" [label=•]
        }
    }

    subgraph clusterC {
        label=C
        {
            rank=same
            "0C"
            "1C"
            "2C" -> "0C" [label=•]
        }
    }

    subgraph clusterD {
        label=D
        {
            rank=same
            "0D"
            "1D"
            "2D" -> "0D" [label=•]
        }
    }

    subgraph clusterE {
        label=E
        {
            rank=same
            "0E"
            "1E"
            "2E" -> "0E" [label=•]
        }
    }

    subgraph clusterF {
        label=F
        {
            rank=same
            {node [shape = doublecircle] "0F" "1F"}
            "2F" -> "0F" [label=•]
        }
    }

    "0A" -> "1B" [label=a]
    "1A" -> "2B" [label=a]
    "0B" -> "1C" [label=b]
    "1B" -> "2C" [label=b]
    "0C" -> "1D" [label=c]
    "1C" -> "2D" [label=c]
    "0D" -> "1E" [label=d]
    "1D" -> "2E" [label=d]
    "0E" -> "1F" [label=e]
    "1E" -> "2F" [label=e]
}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked very well, and much simpler to read than the other answers.

Comment: You're not using rankdir, are you?  It seems you're using `rank=same` instead, which breaks the graph: the order of the nodes in the clusters changes.