# Graphs and subgraphs layout

Tags: graphviz, subgraph

Using `graphviz` I want to generate the following graph (manually written in `tikz` for now):

[image: s://i.stack.imgur.com/Szu8i.png]

I currently succeeded in writing a `dot` file giving me the following result (there is a single node using html for the Pile table on the top, and one node also using html for every grey box):

[image]

But unfortunately I was not able to keep the layout of grey boxes that I like AND to have the grey boxes on the right of the Pile table. I read carefully [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777722/top-down-subgraphs-left-right-inside-subgraphs) and tried things with `rank`, `subgraphs` and `rankdir` without success.

Is there any hope to reach my goal with `dot` ?

EDIT: here is the complete `dot` file I have currently

```
digraph structs {
node [shape=plaintext]
subgraph stack {
label = STACK;
stack [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="white">
<TR><TD><i>Nom</i></TD><TD><i>Type</i></TD><TD><i>Portée</i></TD><TD><i>Valeur</i></TD></TR>
<TR><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">list2</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">référence</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">main</TD><TD PORT="port_140407657518560" BGCOLOR="chartreuse">0x7f
b334a23ac0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">list1</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">référence</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">main</TD><TD PORT="port_140407657518032" BGCOLOR="chartreuse">0x7f
b334a23ac0</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
>
];
}
subgraph heap {
label = HEAP;
  struct_140407658920640 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD COLSPAN="6">0x7fb334a23ac0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD COLSPAN="6"><u>list</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD PORT="port_child0">0x955e80</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child1">0x956360</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child2">0x956040</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child3">0x7fb3348cbbb0</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child4">0x7fb3348cbc30</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child5">0x7fb3348cbc70</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>>];
  struct_9789056 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x955e80</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>int</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>3</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child0 -> struct_9789056;
  struct_9790304 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x956360</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>int</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>42</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child1 -> struct_9790304;
  struct_9789504 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x956040</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>int</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>17</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child2 -> struct_9789504;
  struct_140407657511856 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x7fb3348cbbb0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>str</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>"go"</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child3 -> struct_140407657511856;
  struct_140407657511984 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x7fb3348cbc30</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>str</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>"feu"</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child4 -> struct_140407657511984;
  struct_140407657512048 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x7fb3348cbc70</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>str</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>"partez"</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child5 -> struct_140407657512048;
}
stack:port_140407657518560 -> struct_140407658920640;
stack:port_140407657518032 -> struct_140407658920640;
}
```

Comment: (Hope springs eternal!)  Yep, probably "can do" - but please provide your current dot program.

Comment: @sroush I added the dot code. Sorry for the formatting, it is something generated, so I didn't needed, up to know, to have it well formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor changes

- changed subgraphs to clusters (see https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf)
- added invisible edge to drive cluster positioning

```
digraph structs {
node [shape=plaintext]
subgraph cluster_stack {  // changed to cluster
graph [peripheries=0]     // no box around this cluster
label = STACK;
stack [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="white">
<TR><TD><i>Nom</i></TD><TD><i>Type</i></TD><TD><i>Porté?e</i></TD><TD><i>Valeur</i></TD></TR>
<TR><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">list2</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">ré?fé?rence</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">main</TD><TD PORT="port_140407657518560" BGCOLOR="chartreuse">0x7f
b334a23ac0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">list1</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">ré?fé?rence</TD><TD BGCOLOR="chartreuse">main</TD><TD PORT="port_140407657518032" BGCOLOR="chartreuse">0x7f
b334a23ac0</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
>
];
}
subgraph cluster_heap {  // changed to cluster
label = HEAP;
  struct_140407658920640 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD COLSPAN="6">0x7fb334a23ac0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD COLSPAN="6" port="myport"><u>list</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD PORT="port_child0">0x955e80</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child1">0x956360</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child2">0x956040</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child3">0x7fb3348cbbb0</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child4">0x7fb3348cbc30</TD>
<TD PORT="port_child5">0x7fb3348cbc70</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>>];
  struct_9789056 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x955e80</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>int</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>3</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child0 -> struct_9789056;
  struct_9790304 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x956360</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>int</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>42</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child1 -> struct_9790304;
  struct_9789504 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x956040</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>int</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>17</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child2 -> struct_9789504;
  struct_140407657511856 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x7fb3348cbbb0</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>str</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>"go"</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child3 -> struct_140407657511856;
  struct_140407657511984 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x7fb3348cbc30</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>str</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>"feu"</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child4 -> struct_140407657511984;
  struct_140407657512048 [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" BGCOLOR="gray">
<TR><TD>0x7fb3348cbc70</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><u>str</u></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>"partez"</TD></TR>
</TABLE>>];
struct_140407658920640:port_child5 -> struct_140407657512048;
}
edge [constraint=false]  // do not use next two edges to position nodes/clusters
stack:port_140407657518560 -> struct_140407658920640:myport
stack:port_140407657518032 -> struct_140407658920640
// add invisible edge & use to position nodes/clusters
edge [constraint=true style=invis]  
stack:port_140407657518032 -> struct_9789056
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. But your solution requires to know the left most node of the heap, isn't it ? Since I generate this automatically, I need a solution to know automatically to which node of the heap I should connect the invisible edge.

Comment: A quick test shows that the invisible edge is not needed!  Just go with the constraint=false attributes